# Postgres Date Cast from a String

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, casting

I have a Date/time in the format DD-MON-YYHH24MISS. I have to cast this as date and then sort the data by date in desc order. The following query is giving erroneous results:

SELECT to_date(substring(td."date", 1,10), 'dd-MON-yy') as date
from tbl order by date desc;

Whats the error here? I get dates as '2122-01-08'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be taking a substring of the first *nine*, not ten, characters:

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(SUBSTRING("date", 1, 9), 'DD-MON-YY') AS date
FROM tbl
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with **varchar** and **timestamp** data types:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl ("date" TIMESTAMP);
INSERT INTO tbl ("date") VALUES ('01.01.2022 12:53:21');
INSERT INTO tbl ("date") VALUES ('05.09.2022 21:01:18');
INSERT INTO tbl ("date") VALUES ('22.03.2022 20:13:10');
INSERT INTO tbl ("date") VALUES ('04.05.2022 21:00:00');

SELECT "date"::DATE
FROM tbl
ORDER BY "date"::DATE DESC
```

Returns:

| date |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 12:53:21 |
| 2022-09-05 21:01:18 |
| 2022-03-22 20:13:10 |
| 2022-05-04 21:00:00 |

| date |
| --- |
| 2022-09-05 |
| 2022-05-04 |
| 2022-03-22 |
| 2022-01-01 |